# How to disable telerik tooltip using a checkbox?

Tags: checkbox, telerik, postback, tooltip

I have an intranet (office) website in which I am using telerik tooltip to guide users about every link, buttons etc, it is a little help system that allows the new users to know what this link do and what that link do. I was thinking that while it will be helpful to new users it will be a hindrance for old users so it will be better if user can toggle the tooltip system so I placed a checkbox below with label "Enable Help System", but I can't seem to figure out the logic through which I can disable the tooltip to appear as user uncheck the box, the Enabled = false property is not working and tooltip still appearing even after postback.

Any ideas/advices ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could either set Visible=false (in which case, the tooltip control will not be rendered on the page at all), or as an alternative - you could set ShowEvent=FromCode (in case you are using some other event to show the tooltip - OnMouseOver etc.)